# My Table View is not Reloading When I type in the Search Bar to Retrieve the Google Books Information

Tags: ios, swift, project, google-books

This is my controller that I am using to lookup the specific books. When I type in the search bar, no book information is displayed back to me while I type or after I finish typing. I would like to understand why and find a solution that would remedy this problem.

```
import UIKit

class TextbookSearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var booksFound = [[String: AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    func queryBooks(bookTitle: String) {
        let stringURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=\(bookTitle)"
        guard let url = URL(string: stringURL) else {
            print("Problem with URL")
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
        let urlSession = URLSession.shared
        let queryTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let jsonData = data else {
                print("No Information could be Found:")
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
                let tableItems = json["Items"] as! [[String: AnyObject]]
                self.booksFound = tableItems

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            } catch {
                print("Error with JSON: ")
            }
        }
        queryTask.resume()
    }
}

extension TextbookSearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return booksFound.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookCell", for: indexPath)

        if let volumeInfo = self.booksFound[indexPath.row]["volumeInfo"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = volumeInfo["title"] as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = volumeInfo["subtitle"] as? String
        }
        return cell
    }
}

extension TextbookSearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        let bookTitle = searchBar.text?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
        self.queryBooks(bookTitle: bookTitle!)
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? What is happening compared to what you expect to happen?

Comment: @rmaddy I am able to segue to this view. When I am in this view the search bar and table view shows but once I begin to type in the search bar the query seems to not return values into the table view.

Comment: 1. You make no attempt to handle text entered into the search bar. 2. The `UISearchBarDelegate` method that you show in your question isn't any method in the delegate protocol. 3. Is the search bar delegate set at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you forget to set `UISearchBar` `delegate`

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar! {
  didSet {
    searchBar.delegate = self
  }
}
```

Also, you need below in place of `func searchBarButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar)`

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // your code
}
```

Key in response is `items` not `Items`

Use `json["items"]` in place of json["Items"]

Complete code:

```
import UIKit

class TextbookSearchViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar! {
        didSet {
            searchBar.delegate = self
        }
    }
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView! {
        didSet {
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.dataSource = self
        }
    }

    var booksFound = [[String: AnyObject]]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

}

extension TextbookSearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return booksFound.count
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BookCell", for: indexPath)

        if let volumeInfo = self.booksFound[indexPath.row]["volumeInfo"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
            cell.textLabel?.text = volumeInfo["title"] as? String
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = volumeInfo["subtitle"] as? String
        }
        return cell
    }
}

extension TextbookSearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {
    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        let bookTitle = searchBar.text?.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed)
        queryBooks(bookTitle: bookTitle!)
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func queryBooks(bookTitle: String) {
        let stringURL = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=\(bookTitle)"
        guard let url = URL(string: stringURL) else {
            print("Problem with URL")
            return
        }
        let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
        let urlSession = URLSession.shared
        let queryTask = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { [weak self] (data, response, error) in
            guard let jsonData = data else {
                print("No Information could be Found:")
                return
            }
            do {
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]

                guard let tableItems = json["items"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] else {
                    self?.booksFound = [[String: AnyObject]]()
                    return
                }

                print(tableItems)
                self?.booksFound = tableItems

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            } catch {
                print("Error with JSON: ")
            }
        }
        queryTask.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be set in the storyboard. But there is so many other problems besides this.

Comment: @rmaddy I am fairly new to Swift and wanted to see if this cool project could be done. Could you possibly comment on the other things that you see wrong with this controller?

Comment: @Satish I implemented both of those suggestions and nothing changes. I am able to type in the search bar and the information from the query function I created is supposed to return some google books information based on the text I input but the tables are not filling with various books.

Comment: @JustinReddick just check its returning `json`. check by adding a debugger or `print` statement

Comment: @JustinReddick in place of `json["Items"]` use `json["Items"]`. Its small `i` in place of capital `I`

Comment: @Satish the queryBooks function seems to not be firing even after the reference , 'self.queryBooks(bookTitle: bookTitle!)' was given to the search bar delegate

Comment: @Satish I have placed print statements throughout the Controller to see what going on and nothing is being output.

Comment: @JustinReddick I have updated code above and its working fine if search bar `delegate` is set. Just replace your code with above mentioned under `extension`

Comment: @Satish What about the second extension for the UISearchBarDelegate? Did you just combine them into one?

Comment: Yes, I have moved code to `extension` just remove your function `queryBooks(bookTitle: String)` and `extension TextbookSearchViewController: UISearchBarDelegate` and use what I have provided

Comment: @JustinReddick I have provided the complete code for  `TextbookSearchViewController` above.